# How to receive data in Arduino through RS-232 port

Tags: arduino, hardware, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to receive data from RS-232 port from a cash register machine. The problem is whatever I do I cant connect to it via Arduino. I just want some ideas, if you want to write me the code you can do it so I have an idea about it.

Comment: I want to say that I have already divided the rx,tx and gnd coming from the cash register

Comment: Arduino's TTL Serial (5V) is electrically very different from RS232. There are MAX232 IC to interface.

Comment: And there is no other way @datafiddler

Comment: If you only need one direction ( receive RS232 ) and thus you don't need to create voltages > 5V and < 0V,  you might want to build a voltage divider and inverter.  A MAX232 is definitely easier, safer and cheaper.